# C++: specializing member requires «template<>» syntax

Tags: c++, static, g++

What am I doing wrong?

```
template<class T>
class Binder
{
public:
    static std::vector< Binder< T >* > all;
    Node<T>* from;
    Node<T>* to;
    Binder(Node<T>* fnode, Node<T>* tonode)
    {
        from = fnode;
        to = tonode;
        Binder<T>::all.push_back(this);
    }
};

std::vector<Binder<int>*> Binder<int>::all = std::vector< Binder<int>* >(); //here it is
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of the static member is interpreted by the compiler as a specialization (actually, it *is* a specialization: you are giving a declaration that is specific to `T = int`). This can be fixed by adding `template<>` before the definition.

Defining static members in templates is a bit of a bummer: the static member needs to be defined outside a header, and that is possible only if you already know all the possible `T` for your binder.

For instance, right now you are defining it for `T=int`. Now, if you start using `Binder<double>` somewhere, the static member is going to be an undefined reference.

Comment: Static members for template classes can be defined in the header.

Comment: @Timo Does not seem so. I moved the template code in bla.h that I included in bla.cpp and main.cpp. I think that compilers don't know how to "unify" global variables the same way they do for inline functions

    doudou@demeter:~/tmp$ g++ main.cpp bla.cpp/tmp/ccdgiTrw.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Binder<int>::all'
    /tmp/ccXM1TWJ.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status</pre>

Comment: See $3.2/5 in the standard. It specifically allows multiple definition of static data members for class templates assuming they're in different translation units.