# Declare an iterator template

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, iterator, mingw

I'm working on making a linkedlist class for some practice.  I want it to support iteration, so I've given it an iterator class.  However, I'm getting some compilation errors.  Here is a shortened version of my code.

t.cpp

```
#include "t.hpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

t.hpp

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_HPP
#define LINKEDLIST_HPP 1

#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>    

template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    template <typename V> class Iterator;
    template <typename V> struct ListNode;
public:
    typedef Iterator<T> iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
private:
    template <typename V>
    class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {
    public:
        Iterator<T>& operator++();
    private:
        friend class LinkedList;
        Iterator() = delete;
        Iterator(ListNode<T>* node) : current_{node} { }
        ListNode<T>* current_;
    };

    template <typename V>
    struct ListNode
    {
        T value_;
        ListNode<T>* next_;
    };

    ListNode<T>* head_;
    ListNode<T>* tail_;
};

template <typename T> inline
typename LinkedList<T>::iterator LinkedList<T>::begin() 
{
    return iterator{head_}; 
}

template <typename T> inline
typename LinkedList<T>::iterator LinkedList<T>::end()
{
    return iterator{nullptr};
}

template <typename T> inline
typename LinkedList<T>::iterator& 
LinkedList<T>::iterator::operator++()
{
    current_ = current_->next_;
    return *this;
}

#endif
```

Now I have a sneaking suspicion that the line `typedef Iterator<T> iterator` either doesn't quite work like I think it should, or it is bad practice by concealing the fact that `iterator` is a template type.  However, I don't get any  obvious warnings from my compiler (mingw32-g++ 4.8.1) about that.

I'm compiling this using

```sh
$ mingw32-g++ -g -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu++11 t.cpp
```

which gives me the error

```
t.hpp:60:33: error: specializing member 'LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::operator++' requires 'template<>' syntax
 typename LinkedList<T>::iterator& 
                                 ^
```

Okay, so I give it the template syntax there.

```
template <typename T> inline
typename LinkedList<T>::iterator<T>& 
LinkedList<T>::iterator::operator++() { }
```

Where I then get the compilation error

```
t.hpp:60:25: error: non-template 'iterator' used as template
 typename LinkedList<T>::iterator<T>& 
                         ^  
t.hpp:60:25: note: use 'LinkedList<T>::template iterator' to indicate that it is a template

t.hpp:60:25: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
                ^
```

Okay, so I use `template`

```
template <typename T> inline
typename LinkedList<T>::template iterator<T>& 
LinkedList<T>::iterator::operator++() { }
```

And get this error now

```
t.hpp:60:45: error: specializing member 'LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::operator++' requires 'template<>' syntax
 typename LinkedList<T>::template iterator<T>& 
                                             ^
```

Which is where I get stuck.  I've read these questions

- [specializing member S::display requires ‘template<>’ syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16493187/3076272)
- [Why does this code give the error, "template specialization requires 'template<>'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15723850/3076272)
- [C++: specializing member requires «template<>» syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12525012/3076272)

which seem to indicate that I need to put a `template<>` somewhere.  I'm just not sure I understand where it should go.

How should I attempt to do what I'm doing here?

Comment: I don't think you really wanted to make the iterator itself a template in the first place.

Comment: Nor the node, for that matter.

Comment: @chris I realize after your comments that there isn't a point to having either of those things be templates, and removing that fixed all of my errors.

Comment: @T.C. If either (or both) of you wish to leave an answer to that effect I'd be happy to accept and upvote.

Comment: I'm actually doing this for a class right now.  I'm curious if you've actually iterated through a list?  We had our entire `iterator` class under `public` and it seems that your default ctor isn't permitted since it's `private`.  It appears to me that someone won't be able to do `LinkedList<int>::Iterator iter;`  Then later assign it to `begin()`.

Comment: @TriHard8 Yeah, it works fine.  If you look under the definition of `Iterator` it says `friend class LinkedList;` which gives `LinkedList` access to the constructor.  I've also `typedef`'d the `Iterator` as `iterator` which is what users of the class would have access to.

Comment: @Dannnno cool.  It's always fun looking at other people's code to see how drastically different the same thing can be accomplished.